# Is "of each" a phrase?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

> Those interests, I contend, authorise the subjection of individual spontaneity to external control, only in respect to those actions **of each**, which concern the interest of other people

Essay: On Liberty

Author: John Stuart Mill

Is "each" pronoun for "action" here?
And does the meaning differ if we drop (of each)?

Answer (score 1):

In this passage, *each* stands for *each individual* or *each person*. Mill is making a general claim about when people's free action (individual spontaneity) can justly be controlled. He claims that this control, justified by "those interests" (presumably defined in the preceding paragraphs), can only justly take place when a person's actions (*or*, **the actions of each**) concern other people's interests.

You could remove *of each* and the sentence would probably still be clear, but by using it Mill emphasizes that he is fundamentally talking about people--their freedoms, actions, and duties--not the abstract concept of action.